# How to decrypt asp.net owin token in asp.net core manually?

Tags: asp.net-core, machinekey

I have an existing application which generates owin identity token with machine key approach. The same token is used to authenticate various application. One of the application is now in asp.net core. Is there any way to use same owin generated identity token in asp.net core?

or we can decode that token manually in asp.net core

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share *anything* between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core when using machine keys. The only way to be able to decrypt something in ASP.NET Core set by an ASP.NET app is if 1) the ASP.NET app(s) utilize the data protection provider 2) the data protection provider key ring is persisted to filesystem or network location accessible by all the apps (ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core alike) and all the apps utilize the same application name.

The [docs go into great detail on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score -1):

You can decrypt the Access Token returned from the authorization code flow directly by using `IDataProtector`.  we implement the `IDataProtector` interface and use the `System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect method`.
 To Make helper Method to decrypt the OWIN ticket

```
private class MachineKeyProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purpose =
    {
        typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
        "Access_Token",
        "v1"
    };

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purpose);
    }
}
```

To get ClaimsIdentity and a Dictionary of Properties. we just create an instance and pass in the Token to get the decrypted Ticket

```
var secureDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyProtector());
AuthenticationTicket ticket = secureDataFormat.Unprotect(accessToken);
```

Above  AuthenticationTicket itself contains the ClaimsIdentity and a Dictionary of Properties.
refer [IDataProtector Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.idataprotector?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware is not supported in .NET Core.